# How can I find a Mentor?

Tags: software-industry, careers

I am currently in the midst of switching careers into the tech field, specifically with the goal of becoming employed as a software developer. I hope to find someone interested in mentoring and assisting me with my learning process. I am extremely devoted and passionate and will not waste anyone's efforts. How do I find such a person?

I currently am familiar with Python, HTML, and CSS. Also, I have a nice basis of general computer knowledge and workings. I am looking for someone who is willing to guide me towards important skills and give feedback on my code so that I am able to get an entry level position.

Comment: I presume you're hoping someone will do this for free? It is possible to hire mentors but my guess is that's not what you want

Comment: I am seeking someone who enjoys teaching for the fun of it. I am looking for general guidance (not a huge time commitment) and a person who just enjoys helping someone new.

Comment: "I am looking for someone who is willing to guide me towards important skills and give feedback on my code so that I am able to get an entry level position." That would be you and a few zillion people.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a tutor, not a mentor...

Answer (score 2):

Find a friend who has these skills and is willing to guide you. Of find a co-worker who.. etc. Or. find a class or two which covers this material.

Answer (score 2):

The only barrier between you and learning to program is yourself! In fact, you're on stackexchange, and stackoverflow is one of the biggest resources for guidance in regards to programming you can find on the web. I understand you're looking for an individual to bounce ideas off of, sure, but you also have a wealth of knowledge at your fingertips!

@keshlam is correct, if you are interested in this field chances are you have a friend or a coworker already knee-deep in computer science. Personally I work as a software developer and if anyone comes up and asks me questions(which actually happens quite often) I'm more than willing to help them or point them in the right direction. I think the biggest barrier to this is you going up to someone and saying "Hey, I was kind of interested in this stuff... is there any way you could show me how to do such and such?"

I've done as much as written tutorials for those people who have asked me and assisted with their homework/made study guides for them. The programming community is very open and very willing to help each other for the most part, even if you're just starting out, but you do have to take that first step and just ask.

If you don't have someone you can turn to in this regard, as another point you can check out many free online courses at places like https://www.udacity.com/ or pick up skills from http://www.w3schools.com/ , http://tympanus.net/codrops/ , http://codepen.io/ , https://stackoverflow.com/

Another big way to learn is to look at programming books. Probably the best books out there in regards to programming are from O'Reilly. http://www.oreilly.com/  - Their authors are fantastic at breaking down complex ideas and theories. They even have online courses, though they are not free and I hear they may not be the best, but the books are very, very solid.

There's really so many ways to learn it's kind of absurd, but if you really feel you need a "mentor" or a "tutor" you can always hire one. Just do a search for programming tutors, though I warn you, they're usually pretty expensive!

Best of Luck!

Comment: Perhaps what I am looking for isn't directly assistance, I can learn fairly well on my own. I have already taken introduction classes to computer science (MIT) and am currently working on TreeHouse. I definitely will pick up some books.

I am looking more for advice one what I need before I start to apply for positions. The tech field seems huge, and I have no idea what I might need to know to get an entry level position.

Comment: @TwoPointOH Do you have any prior experience developing in any capacity? Or has it been more hobby based?

Comment: I have done a fair amount of coding and so far it has been hobby-based. I am looking to learn more and develop myself as professional.

Comment: @TwoPointOH I would suggest, if you have a current position, to look into doing something to make work life easier for your current company. It can be something as simple as doing a few calculations in a spreadsheet or creating an internal website that houses information. It's pretty difficult, from my experience, to get a job as an entry-level developer based on enthusiasm and time spent on learning alone. To give you an idea I started my software developer career as a customer service rep without a degree and little coursework, just a lot of passion and willingness to work

Comment: I saw a need in the department and demonstrated my abilities by creating programs that significantly decreased the work load of my peers, and gained the respect and interest of my employers. It took a lot of work(about a year and a half of developing basically for free) to get to the point where I was trusted even without the prerequisite credentials. Now I have a job as a developer I love and the beginning of a career I can be proud of. You really have to put yourself out there without the coursework, especially if you're like me and need the job to get the degree.